# dnsmasq - DNS server isolation

Tags: linux, dns, process

Can somebody please explain how to isolate process of the DNS server in a certain directory? I am using `dnsmasq` and the process should not be able to access the root tree?

What exactly is process isolation?

- I’ve created separate directory for jail `/home/dnsmasq/jail`
- I’ve copied `/usr/sbin/dnsmasq` to `/home/dnsmasq/jail/usr/sbin/`
- `ldd /usr/sbin/dnsmasq` gave me the proper libraries for `dnsmasq`

Copied libraries to jail directory:

```
/home/dnsmasq/lib64/
```

I don't know if something else is needed.

Comment: What exactly is "outside of the root tree"?

Comment: sorry I'll edit the question. The process should not be able to access the root tree.